# Looping multiple correlations filtered by group in dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, correlation

What is the best/most efficient way to loop correlations based on groups through a database and output the rho value into a separate data frame to be saved out as a csv file?

Example of my data frame (brain_df):

| brain_measure | surfacearea_est | vol_est | network |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| area_1 | 0.55 | 0.823 | Vis |
| area_2 | 0.23 | 0.246 | Vis |
| area_3 | 0.15 | 0.442 | Vis |
| area_4 | 0.75 | 0.653 | Vis |

There are 50 different areas in "brain_measure" which repeat across 8 different "network", amounting to 400 rows.

I would like to run correlations between "surfacearea_est" and "vol_est" across "brain_measure" within "network", grab and output rho value into a new database.

I can do this manually and repeatedly run:

```
network_vis_df = brain_df %\>% filter(network== 'Vis')

cor.test(network_vis_df$surfacearea_est, network_vis_df$vol_est, method='spearman')
```

across my list of networks, but obviously I would like to try not to do this.

I made a list of all my networks looking like this:

```
network_list = c('limbA','limbB','limbC','cing-op','pfc','par','motor','vis')
```

and empty data frame to store the output:

```
corr_output = NULL
```

I think I would have to loop based on this list above, such as:

```
for (network_type in network_list){
    network_type_df = brain_df %\>% filter(network== 'network_type')
    cor.test(network_type_df$surfacearea_est, network_type_df$vol_est, method='spearman')
}
```

I also don't really know how to grab the rho value of the correlation output, I'm thinking "grep"? And output into the new data frame.

Comment: `corr_output = NULL` doesn't create an empty dataframe, but `corr_output = data.frame()` does.

Comment: Define what is meant by “loop correlations. Read the help page for `cor.test`. The results are delivered in a list.